# How to query object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular6

It's a twofold question. I have a ListOfIds class in my Angular app that contains three arrays of numbers. I receive an object from the server which is observed as ListOfIds type. When I stingify and console.log() the object it displays array names and values in each array. So I know that data is coming through. But when I try to assign the object to an instance of that class and pull out one of the arrays, I get the undefined error. How can I pull out the array I need and assign it into a variable that I could iterate over?

```
export class ListOfIds {
    FirstList: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
    SecondList: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
    ThirdList: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
}
```

.ts code

```
instanceOfListOfIds: ListOfIds;

this._httpService.updateEntity(this.myEntity).subscribe(
      (objectFromServer) => {
       this.instanceOfListOfIds = objectFromServer;
       console.log('Display in console: ' + this.instanceOfListOfIds.FirstList); // undefined
       console.log('items from the server: ' + JSON.stringify(objectFromServer)); // displays array names and values
}
```

This leads to the second question. myEntity has the same three arrays of numbers. In the same http call, I'd like to reassign all ids in FirstList that came from the server into FirstList of myEntity. Not sure if it's going to work as the undefined error stepped in the way. Many thanks in advance.

```
this.myEntity.FirstList.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (item.id == 0) {
    item.id = this.instanceOfListOfIds.FirstList.indexOf[index];
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the output of this line at run-time please:
       `console.log('items from the server: ' + JSON.stringify(objectFromServer));`

Comment: @JoshWulf the output from the stringified object is: items from the server: {"workId":2,"FirstList":[],"SecondList":[1,1082,1083,1093],"ThirdList":[]} For some reason myEntity object and all arrays inside it are throwing the "undefined" error. Eventhough, I newed the object and all arrays inside ngOnInit() function.

Comment: I'd need to see the implementation of `this._httpService.updateEntity` is it a standard library, or custom code?

Comment: @JoshWulf this is my http put method. I assume it's a standard one. `updateEntity(entityToUpdate: Work): Observable<ListOfIds> {
        return this.httpClient.put<ListOfIds>(this.baseUrl, entityToUpdate, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        })
    }`